# Devemos notificar a tag [notificação] para que desapareça?

Tags: debate, tag-específica

Há razão para a tag [notificação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/notifica%c3%a7%c3%a3o) existir?

Ela era principalmente usada em perguntas sobre Android onde, ou era mal usada, ou se referia ao sistema de notificação do Android, que tem uma tag própria: [android-notification](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-notification).

Essas eu já resolvi, faltam as outras cujos temas não domino.

Não são muitas, analisem cada uma e decidam se deve manter, eliminar ou usar outra.

Comment: Já pensei nisso, está na minha lista. É uma boa dúvida, eu não tenho certeza porque ela é usada para outras coisas. Me parece, mas posso estar enganado que ela pode existir separada com função própria. Mas também reconheço que ela acaba gerando problemas porque as pessoas usam para qualquer notificação. Pode-se considerá-la como ambígua e nunca deveria usar. Não sei. Ou pode-se dar um motivo específico para usá-la. Vou analisar para ver o que eu posso fazer e atualizo aqui, talvez dando uma resposta.

Comment: Nas relacionadas com Android foi fácil decidir, em ralação às outras tenho as mesmas dúvidas que você, não em todas porque há algumas em que é evidente o seu mau uso.

Comment: Quando eu bati o olho dias atrás vi algumas com mau uso.

Comment: Dei uma olhada nisso e havia 13 perguntas. Tirei de 9: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54795/132, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131858/132, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/128798/132, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/122283/132, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32962/132, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146845/132, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/116696/132, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/57253/132, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/70729/132 - Em todas elas a tag ou era redundante, ou era desnecessária, ou era uma pergunta tão ruim que qualquer tag seria ruim. Faltam 4 que achei mais difíceis de analisar.

Comment: Essas perguntas também têm o problema de que geralmente não está claro se a pessoa quer criar uma notificação na barra do sistema ou se quer apenas uma forma com que o servidor notifique a aplicação via push (mas não necessariamente criar a notificação na barra). A gente acaba tendo que perguntar.

Comment: @PabloAlmeida sim, porque de alguma forma ela é ambígua. Talvez devesse existir a tag `system-tray-notification`, a `push-notification` já existe.