# Deveríamos utilizar a tag [javascript-eventos]?

Tags: debate, suporte, tag-específica

Hoje temos **175 perguntas** utilizando a tag [**javascript-eventos**].

Uma vez que a linguagem JavaScript *não tem construções de eventos*, essa tag me parece não fazer sentido.

Eventos não são parte da linguagem JavaScript em si (que pode ser compilada ou executada em muitos contextos), eles são parte do DOM.

O fórum em inglês descontinuou o uso da tag movendo-a para [dom-events] e sugeriu **o uso de alternativas** como:

- [dom-events]
- [jquery-events]
- [backbone-events]
- biblioteca / ambiente + [events]
- [node.js] + [events]

Outra possibilidade seria o **uso de tags separadas**: [javascript] [dom]  [eventos].

Seria interessante adotarmos alguma dessas práticas?

Comment: Acho que tem a ver com https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5336/101, mas é um boa discussão, espero que cheguemos a uma conclusão, precisamos manter um padrão no site e considerar o uso específico.

Comment: @Maniero pensei em sugerir a edição da tag que está vazia mas acho que é preciso saber o posicionamento da comunidade à respeito.

Comment: Já deixo minha opinião contrária à possibilidade de tags separadas pelo fato que `[event]` poderia se referir a muita coisa fora do contexto de JavaScript/DOM, dando liberdade para ter, em uma mesma tag, eventos do DOM, eventos do Laravel, eventos em bancos de dados, perguntas conceituais de arquiteturas orientadas a eventos, etc. Acho que não ficaria uma tag organizada.

Comment: Sim, é importante debater essas coisas.

Comment: A propria tag eventos, ou tal subdivisão me parece um baita exagero, **pessoalmente** acho que as tags deveriam falar de tecnologias (linguagem, APIs e frameworks) especificas, por exemplo, no JavaScript temos nativamente as API DOM e File, logo para mim tags sobre isso fazem sentido, agora eventos ou events fica complicado, por seriam "sub-interfaces" de duas interfaces especificas, Events e outra (com citado DOM ou talvez WindowOrGlobal), complica demais querermos tornar algo generico, ou tornar algo especifico que esta "misturado" em 2 locais [...]

Comment: [...] ao meu ver muita coisa se resolver com a tag da linguagem + API especifica (quando não esbarra de 2 locais), isso porque muitas vezes a tag de api especifica também pode ser redundante, já que por certas (muitas) vezes a pessoa quer de uma forma e acabam propondo soluções MUITO MELHORES com outras APIs. Resumindo, tem muita sub-tag que só serve para confundir mesmo e realmente não conheço ninguém que faça questão se assinar o feed (rss/atom) dessas "sub-tags", deveriam ser removidas do sistema (apesar de não fazerem mal algum)

Comment: **Relacionado:** [Vocês conseguem ver algum efeito de dinamismo no site quando se usa as tags efeito e dinamico?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7810/3635) (relacionado pelo simples fato de inicialmente o autor esta tentando buscar um propósito comum, como resolver as tags, a maioria ao menos e muito do que for discutido aqui pode ser útil lá e vice-versa)

Comment: Acho que no mínimo a tag [javascript-eventos] faz aplicação errada da linguagem. Tags separadas também acho amplo demais.

Comment: @AndreiaLopes sim, dá para entender seu ponto de vista, porque eventos é algo amplo mesmo, como citei no primeiro comentário, as  coisas se misturam, e no geral quase todo mundo entende, mas as coisas especificas é que vão complicar, mas como eu concordo nisto contigo, (pessoalmente) discordo de `[javascript] [dom] [eventos]`, DOM faz sentido para mim ter tag, agora eventos é muito complicado. Devo que felizmente usam até que bem a tag DOM, acho que porque as pessoas nem saibam o que é isso, só usa quem entende o minimo, mas se fosse muito usada provavelmente seria outro problema também.